# Why do most of the people visit India to achieve high spiritual state or for becoming great?

Tags: history, yoga, culture, india, spirituality

I am always curious to know why do most of the people visit India to achieve high spiritual state or for becoming great ?
Example Steve Jobs, Mark Zukerburg etc.. the list is long.

Comment: People with financial/technical acumen and who could prosper in foreign countries will not visit India for material gains.  People like Mark Zukerburg may visit India for expansion of business.  Only people with intention of getting SPIRITUAL benefit, though do not fully understand what it is, will visit India with the hope of meeting a SPIRITUAL person like Sri Ramana Maharshi.  So Your question needs to be edited, in my view.  @Sandip Patidar.

Answer (score 1):

All religions are insisting of prayers to God at certain intervals, reading of respective Holy text, following respective customs.

**Vaishnavism, Shaivism, Saakteism,** etc, are religions, being practiced by people under the name of Hinduism aka Sanaatana Dharma.

**Buddhism, Jainism, Christianity, Islam,** etc, are Religions.

Naturally, majority of the people are following any religion, are offering prayers to God at certain intervals, reading of respective Holy text, following respective customs as required.

A minuscule number of people, with sensitive and evolved mind, after following any religion are getting bored as ritualistic life will hit a DEAD END.

A question arises in their minds - What next?

---

Religion and SPIRITUALITY are different.

The purpose of any religion is to show direction towards spirituality.

And, the spiritual practices make a human being realise, not understand, **the God within oneself.**

---

We have to understand that **spirituality has no affiliation** to any religion.

The Question is -  **why do most of the people visit India to achieve high spiritual state?**

Major religions are insisting on following certain rituals, following their respective sacred texts, but do not through light on SPIRITUALITY.

We have to understand that though majority of the people have been following religions like **Vaishnavism, Shaivism, Saakteism,** etc, still India has minuscule percentage of SPIRITUALLY elevated persons.

Be it Sri Vivekananda or Sri Ramana Maharshi, or some other sage, known or unknown, it is their SPIRITUAL AURA that is drawing people from far off places, to understand the TRUTH of life.

For example; Dr. Paul Brunton visited India for this purpose only, roamed India during 1930s and finally met his Guru Sri Ramana Maharshi and attained what he wanted.

He wrote a book ***A Search in Secret India*** on his experiences in India.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Brunton

Comment: I want to say majority of the people do not follow Hinduism properly, only their ritualistic parts. I guess the rest of your answer is correct.

Comment: There's no relegion in our Dharma.... Its wrong translation to English. They have translated Dharma as relegion. So I say your answer is excellent!

Comment: I would like to add this. Its our Dharma which says beyond just offering prayers, your yourself find union with Brahman. When you attain that stage of Brahman, whatever one thinks and wishes will happen. No need of prayer.

Comment: @AkshayS: when one attains union with Brahman, thinking or wishing,ie., desires do not arise.  There will be only ABSOLUTE BLISS.  No need to desire for anything.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv right , that's the final stage. Even in life here, you can attain union with Brahman until your duties are completed in this world!